# Series Question: $(1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{a}{a+2}x+\frac{1.3}{2.4}\frac{a}{a+4}x^2+....)(1+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1.3}{2.4}x^2 +.....)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Resolving $\frac {(a+1)(a+3) .....(a+2n-1)}{a(a+2)....(a+2n)}$ into partial fractions, show that if $a > 0$ and $|x| < 1$ then $(1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{a}{a+2}x+\frac{1.3}{2.4}\frac{a}{a+4}x^2+....)(1+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1.3}{2.4}x^2 +.....) = 1+\frac{a+1}{a+2}x+\frac{(a+1)(a+3)}{(a+2)(a+4)}x^2+....$

How to approach these kind of questions? can any 1 pls give some hints regarding this?

my attempt:

[image]

Comment: Step 1. Are you able to prove that $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(2n+2)\cdot(2n+1)!!}{(2n+1)\cdot(2n+2)!!}x^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$$?

Comment: Step 2. Are you able to compute the Taylor series of $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^a \sqrt{1-x}}\qquad \text{and}\qquad \frac{1}{(1-x)^a}$$ ?

Comment: Step 3. Did you notice that $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^a \sqrt{1-x}}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^a}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$$ ?

Comment: Short answer: this is just the extended binomial theorem / Vandermonde's identity for binomial coefficients of the $\binom{n+\frac{1}{2}}{k}$ kind.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio can u pls have a look at my attempt in image?

Comment: I won't call that an attempt. You just checked those series have a unit convergence radius and wrote down the definition of Cauchy product. Please have a look at the suggested steps to prove your identity and improve your question accordingly.